# Selecting various distinct Classes with an Id in common

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How could I reduce this kind of selector?

```
$("#id .class1, #id .class2, #id .class3, #id .class4, #id .class5").on("mouseover", function(e){
    // code
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
$("#my_id .product, #my_id .date, #my_id .due").on("mouseover", function(e){
    $(this).addClass("edit");
});
```

Comment: Why would you need to reduce this selector? It can be rewritten like `$('#id').find('.class1, .class2, .class3...')`, but is that the only thing you're looking for?

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your markup?

Comment: Depends on your document structure.  Show some of the markup.

Comment: I want to reduce it because indeed are names very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selector overload that uses context.

The *context* can be a jQuery wrapped set or another selector string.

```
$('.class1, .class2, .class3, .class4, .class5', '#id')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the *attribute-starts-with* selector

```
$("#id *[class^='class']");
```

Or if there may be some other `'class...'` class that should not be included,  you can manually filter.

```
$("#id *[class^='class']").filter(function(i, el) {
    return /class\d+\b/.test(el.className);
});
```

This will search for `'class'` plus one or more digits, plus a word boundary.

Comment: But this will also catch `.class666`

Comment: Aye, but that'll also pick up .class6 etc.  If that's desirable, that's fine.

Comment: @Pekka, Paul: Yes, but I really don't the question shows exact code. I think the example is meant to say *"I have similarly  named classes, except for the trailing number"*.

Comment: I wanted make a general question, but indeed I refer to `Selecting various distinct Classes with an Id in common` (title just edited)

Comment: @NomikOS: So there's not necessarily a predictable pattern? Yeah, that would change things quite a bit. ...but if you can rely on some content being present in the class, then there are several selectors that can help. The "starts-with" selector is just one.

Comment: Yes, I added an example, but I already have some good ideas, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to split your selector into two different once, thus removing the repeated `#id`

```
$('#id').find( '.class1, class2, class3, class4, class5')
        .on("mouseover", function(e){
            // code
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method in such cases..

```
$("#id").filter(".class1, .class2, .class3, .class4, .class5").on("mouseover", function(e){
    // code
});
```

//OR  [Attribute starts with selector  ^](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("#id [class^="class"]").on("mouseover", function(e){
    // code
});
```